# Material UI Selected Option Not Showing in Select Box

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, fonts, material-ui

I have the following:

--- before render ---

```
const fontArray = [
  ["Standard", "Standard"], ["Abril FatFace", "'Abril Fatface', cursive"], 
  ["Alfa Slab One", "'Alfa Slab One', cursive"], 
  ["Chonburi", "'Chonburi', cursive"], ["Comfortaa", "'Comfortaa', cursive"], 
  ["Lobster", "'Lobster', cursive"],   ["Pacfico", "'Pacifico', cursive"]
]
```

--- in render ---

```
<FormControl style={{margin: '10px'}}>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="select-font">Font</InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={this.state.font[0]}
    onChange={(evt)=>this.handleFontChange(evt)}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'font',
      id: 'select-font',
    }}
  >
    {fontArray.map((font, index)=>{
      return(
        <MenuItem key={font} value={font}>
          <div style={{fontFamily: `${font[1]}`}}>
            {font[0]}
          </div>
        </MenuItem>
      )
    })}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

And as you can guess the current `font` is held in state.

--- Here is how I handle select change ---

```
  handleFontChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ font: event.target.value })
  };
```

So what I want is to be able to have a font select, where the font is shown. It **almost** works. For example, when I click the select I get:

[image: clicked select]

However, the select itself is empty (even when I've confirmed that state is populated:

[image: empty select]

What am I doing wrong? Maybe material-ui can't handle stylized default text?

EDIT: The two answers below seem close, but not quite right for what I'm trying to do.

If you replace

`<MenuItem key={font} value={font}>`

with

`<MenuItem key={font} value={font[0]}>`

It does replace the font with the correct selected value. Great!
...but it also then replaces `this.state.font` with `this.state.font[0]`. I'm currently attempting to get this to work by changing the handle function like this:

```
handleFontChange = (event, fontArray, stateData) => {
    let newFont = fontArray.filter(i=>{
      if(i[0]==event.target.value){
        return i
      }
    })
    this.setState({ font: newFont })
  };
```

Which seems to set `this.state.font` correctly, but it again doesn't 
seem to want to make the select box show the selected font.

Hmmm....

**SOLVED**

Here is a modification of a solution below:

Using

```
renderValue = (value) => {
    return(
      <div style={{fontFamily: `${value[1]}`}}>
        {value[0]}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

and

```
<...>
<Select
value={this.state.font}
renderValue={() => this.renderValue(this.state.font)}
<...>
```

Gives...

[image: Solved!]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use renderValue to solve this.

```
renderValue = (value) => {
    return value && value[0];
}
```

in render method

```
    <FormControl style={{margin: 10}}>
       <InputLabel htmlFor="select-font">Font</InputLabel>
       <Select
         value={this.state.font}
          renderValue={() => this.renderValue(this.state.font)}
          onChange={evt => this.handleFontChange(evt)}
          inputProps={{
            name: "font",
            id: "select-font"
          }}
        >
        {fontArray.map((font, index) => {
        return (
         <MenuItem key={index} value={font}>
          <div style={{fontFamily: `${font[1]}`}}>
            {font[0]}
          </div>
         </MenuItem>
         );
        })}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

Comment: I have used `renderValue` prop for `Select` component here. In this way you still will have the array of the font and can stylize as per your need

Comment: Perfect! I had not seen that option before. I'll give you props and update the question above. Cheers my dears.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<...>
<Select
value={this.state.font?this.state.font :defaultvlue}
renderValue={() => this.renderValue(this.state.font)}
<...>
```

you can use ternary operator ,if you have data show data else default value